# Minted output pushed to the bottom of the page

Tags: page-breaking, appendices, minted

I've been writing a lab report for school in LaTeX that includes some code in the appendices. However, whenever a block of code takes up less than a page, it is pushed to the bottom. I am using the IEEEtran class.

```
\onecolumn
\appendices
\setminted{linenos}

\section{TITLE 1} \label{code1}
    \inputminted{js}{../path/to/code1.js}

\pagebreak
\section{TITLE 2} \label{code2}
    \inputminted{cpp}{../path/to/code2.cc}

\pagebreak
\section{TITLE 3} \label{code3}
    \inputminted{cpp}{../path/to/code3.cc}
```

Here is an example of what is happening:
[image]

I would like the code to be placed directly below the heading. Are the `\pagebreak`s causing this? How do I fix it?

Comment: You could try `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: @Skillmon I placed it directly below `\appendices`. That seems to have fixed it. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\clearpage` instead of `\pagebreak`; the latter tries to fill pages when, like in the article class with the `twocolumn` option, `\flushbottom` is in force.

This doesn't happen with `\clearpage`.

For the standard classes `article` and `report`, LaTeX sets `\flushbottom` whenever either `twocolumn` or `twoside` is specified. For `book`, `\flushbottom` is in force by default. With other classes, you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting a `\raggedbottom`.

**Explanation (might be unprecise):**

By default LaTeX tries to end every page on the same height, so that if you look at different pages they all look identical in the space which is filled with text. This doesn't work out well, when there are not many choices for the page breaks. In this case the space between unstretchable and unbreakable stuff is stretched, giving much whitespace between your heading and the `minted`-block.

`\raggedbottom` changes this behaviour so that LaTeX doesn't stretch those spaces but leaves the whitespace at the bottom of the page. To return to normal behaviour you can use `\flushbottom`.